# mySQL upgrade caused root ownership of files

Tags: mysql, permissions, upgrade

I recently upgraded mySQL to 5.5 on my Centos box. It failed on restart as some of the files had taken root ownership instead of being owned by mysql user/group. Its working now, after 30 mins of blind terror I managed to get it back online, however there are some files that are still owned by root, and I'm wondering what side effects this may have, or if its even abnormal.

These files are within the mysql directory:

```
drwx------   2 mysql root        4096 Nov 26 06:07 test/
drwx------   2 root  root        4096 Nov 26 06:07 performance_schema/
```

Should I change owenership of thse? if so what user/group should they be? and also, how did this upgrade go so bad in the first place? I used the upgrade tool in WHM.

Comment: unsure why i got down-voted for asking a question whilst trying to learn

Comment: It wasn't my downvote, but mouse over the down arrow; the popup says "*This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful*".
Downvotes without comment may be presumed to be for at least one of those reasons.

Answer (score 3):

Out of the box both of those directories and any files in them are owned by mysql:mysql. It's probably best to make them that on your system.

> How did this happen ? ...

No idea, you probably need to address that to WHM support. You should also get into the habit of performing upgrades in a test environment so that things like this don't come as a shock, you can work out what to do what went wrong and how to fix it before getting anywhere near a production system and 'blind panic'.